# asp:Image does not show the image

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have this code. This code is a part of my menu items:

```
<li class="" id="fifth-li">
    <ul style="visibility: hidden; display: none;" id="fifth-ul">
        <li><asp:HyperLink ID="hpl_undergraduate" runat="server"></asp:HyperLink></li>
        <li><asp:HyperLink ID="hpl_graduate" runat="server"></asp:HyperLink></li>  
    </ul>
        <asp:HyperLink ID="hpl_lessons" runat="server">
        <asp:Image ID="img_lessons"  runat="server" />
        <strong></strong>
        <em id="em_lessons" runat="server"></em>
        </asp:HyperLink>
</li>
```

And this is a part of my .cs code file:

```
em_lessons.InnerHtml = lang["MENU_LESSONS"];
hpl_lessons.Text = lang["MENU_LESSONS"];
hpl_undergraduate.Text = lang["MENU_UNDERGRADUATE"];
hpl_graduate.Text = lang["MENU_GRADUATE"];

hpl_lessons.NavigateUrl = "lessons.html";
hpl_undergraduate.NavigateUrl = "lessons-801.html";
hpl_graduate.NavigateUrl = "lesson-802.html";
img_lessons.ImageUrl = "images/lessons.png"; //Here the image url is defined.
```

This code is for my web page's menu. There are a few more items like this. I add an image to the `img_lessons` object on the codebehind. But after running the page I get this code:

```
<li class="" id="fifth-li">
    <ul style="visibility: hidden; display: none;" id="fifth-ul">
        <li>
            <a id="MainContent_hpl_undergraduate" href="lesson-801.html">
                Undergraduate
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a id="MainContent_hpl_graduate" href="lesson-802.html">
                Graduate
            </a>
        </li>  
    </ul>
    <a id="MainContent_hpl_lessons" href="lessons.html">
        Lessons
    </a>
</li>
```

I was thinking that if I pull out `img_lessons` between `<asp:HyperLink></asp:HyperLink>`, the image would have been shown. But no way. I have changed the codes a bit to be cleaner.

**The point is not about the image path, is about some programmatic incompetence/inconvenience. Because I do not see a `<img id="MainContent_img_lessons" ... />` code on the browser's code view.**

As you can see my image does not look. What do you think?

Regards.

Comment: try img_lessons.ImageUrl = "~/images/lessons.png"; instead of img_lessons.ImageUrl = "images/lessons.png";

Comment: Where/how are you setting the text content of each link? I see "Undergraduate", "Graduate", and "Lessons" in the markup you say you see in the rendered source, but neither your server tag markup nor your code-behind shows where you set that...

Comment: @TiesonT I am getting the texts from an external file in according to language selection.

Comment: "I was thinking that if I pull out img_lessons between <asp:HyperLink></asp:HyperLink>, the image would have been shown..." - you certainly need to do this.  Your current code is replacing the markup inside the hpl_lessons hyperlink by the string from lang["MENU_LESSONS"].  If it still doesn't work, post the modified code.

Comment: @Rahul as I mentioned in the question there is no problem about the path. There is no `<img>` tag in the rendered html code.

Comment: @Joe I have tried before what you have said. Nothing changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do this:

```
hpl_lessons.Text = lang["MENU_LESSONS"];
```

you are wiping out any and all markup from the inside of the hyperlink.

**EDIT:** Since it looks like you already have a `<em>` tag that you have made a server tag, this line:

```
em_lessons.InnerHtml = lang["MENU_LESSONS"];
```

should already be setting viewable text, so, really, you should only have to remove the line mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks. You pointed the problem. Now I am gonna look for a solution.,

Comment: Well Well Well! After commenting this and the other lines like this my problem has gone. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You are clearing the hyperlink innerHTML when you are setting the .Text to lang["MENU_LESSONS"]

What you would need to do is change your markup as follows:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hpl_lessons" runat="server">
    <asp:Image ID="img_lessons"  runat="server" />
    <strong><asp:Literal ID="lit_lessons"/></strong>
    <em id="em_lessons" runat="server"></em>
</asp:HyperLink>
```

And then change your code so that it reads

```
lit_lessons.Text = lang["MENU_LESSONS"];
```